# Phone not receiving calls on deep sleep

Tags: calls, 4.2-jelly-bean, standby, samsung-captivate-glide

I have a [Samsung Captivate Glide](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i927_captivate_glide-4071.php) running android 4.2.2 (an unofficial version of [Vanilla RootBox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2090822) with a kernel called [Litekernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2067896)). This phone is originally for AT&T but it's unlocked and I'm using it on Mexico's carrier Telcel (and I've seen multiple people with the same issue on different countries/carriers).

My issue is that sometimes when someone calls me, the phone rings on their side as if I wasn't picking up and eventually goes to voicemail, but I get no call at all, it's not a sound/vibration setting, I've checked. Also I've read about this kind of issues with multiple phones/carriers.

Once I tested this with another phone and called mine and the call didn't come until I pressed the power button to unlock the screen, waking the phone.

Also I read about some guys using an app called [Wake Lock - PowerManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wl) and using the option PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to keep the phone from going to deep sleep, but of course that consumes the battery much faster.

Does anybody have any idea what could be done?

My phone is rooted and I'm willing to modify the kernel or do any complex action required to fix this...

**Edit**: I forgot to mention I have reflashed this rom several times, every time clearing the cache, dalvik chache, factory reset, etc. And this happened to me in other roms as well...

Comment: I think there is some problem with the radio version currently on your phone . Try flashing a updated radio version.

Comment: I just was about to suggest the same as Ankit. Though I hadn't the similar issue with deep sleep, that solved my trouble I had with my old Wildfire concerning GPS and frequent *freezes* on calls. Especially that the issue persist with different ROMs points to trouble with the radio image.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you use ClockWorkMod , reflash the custom rom after clearing the cache ,factory reset,etc,. If the problem exist try flashing other roms and see if the problems is due to the Custom Rom.
If you are having the  problem only when using the first custom rom, then contact the developer of the Custom Rom and ask tell him about your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I have reflashed this rom (and others) properly several times. I just updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Revert back to your Vanilla Rom (Stock Rom) and check . I had the same pbm in my Galaxy Mini it is solved when i flashed ROM with Different Kernel version .

Comment: Nice suggestion, I'll try it out...

Comment: You should be able to flash a custom kernel onto the rom as well, if it is the same major version.